# TFS 2013 Queries through multiple work item hierarchies

Tags: tfs

RE: TFS/MTM: Plan>Contents>Create query-based suites...

I am trying to get all the test cases returned under each feature for targeted testing. But, the features aren't directly linked to the test cases. The features are linked directly to user stories which are directly linked to Test Cases.

So, How do I get a **list of test cases by Feature** when running query-based?

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot achieve that, multiple work item hierarchies (more than 2 hierarchies) is not supported for work item query.

We can only query 2 hierarchies (Parent/Child), just using the type of query `Work items and direct links` or `Tree of work items` to do that.

So, in your scenario you need to query the test cases by user stories, then filter the stories by Feature.